# App Pool recycled because "Overwhelming Change Notification"

Tags: asp.net, recycle

MY app pool has been recycling on its own recently because "Overwhelming Change Notification" on a folder which only has images. I didnt think that .Net would be dynamically compiling images. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913297/en-us) available that might fix that.

**EDIT**

Looks like there's a followup [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/920970).